# Toggling Anti-Ad discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

my friend has an anti-ad command and he wants to make it toggleable. I tried but I wasn't able to do it. I would be so happy if someone helped me.

Here's the code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
   if "discord.gg" in message.content.lower():
       await message.delete()
       await message.channel.send("Don't advertise your server!")
       await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: how about making an if statement that makes a bool true or false depending on the message, and if it is true run the if statement you currently have

Comment: How would I do it with a @bot.event. I am not so familiar to it.

Comment: if you don't know basic python concepts don't start coding a discord bot.

Comment: an if statement in the on_message def would suffice

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic thing you can build up. This is just a snippet of the things, Rest you can customize yourself accordingly. One more thing, Don't think anyone is gonna give you a step by step tutorial on the stack, Learn the coding first, and if you face any issues you can reach up here.

You can use the if-else statements to make it toggable.

```
#Global Variable TO Store the Data
anti_add = 'off'
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global anti_add
    if "discord.gg" in message.content.lower():
        if anti_add == 'on':
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send("Don't advertise your server!")
            await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def anti_add(ctx):
    global anti_add
    if anti_add == 'off':
        anti_add = 'on'
        await ctx.send('Ads Detector has been Enabled.')
        return anti_add

    else:
        anti_add = 'off'
        await ctx.send('Ads Detector has been Disabled.')
        return anti_add
```